# Nissan Juke 2011

Tags: wheels, suspension, vibration, shaking

My daughter hit the curb when she tried to go forward not realizing it was too close to the curb now the car wobbles/vibrates at  20 to 30 mph (kmh?), I changed the tires and did the alignment, but it is still doing the same thing. The mechanic says nothing  is broken.

Any suggestion before I go to the dealer.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You changed the tires ... did you have the rims checked? I'll lay wager one of them is bent (the one which hit the curb).

Answer (score 2):

When you hit a curb three things can happen that cause vibration:

1. Damage to the suspension or steering rack
2. The wheel may lose its balancing weights. When tires are put on rims the wheels are put on a machine which spins them to show how the weight is unbalanced, and where to stick on weights to make the weight balanced. If those weights come off you can get vibration
3. The rim may be bent from the impact. If a rim is not round then the wheel isn't round and you will get vibration

I suggest if you have a spare tire to switch it with the one that hit the curb. If you change it and the vibration stays then you know you've damaged the suspension, if the vibration goes away then you know it's the wheel.

Comment: Yes all wheel balance change Tires did the alignment made very little difference check with 2 mechanic shops they could not understand once suggested to change the RT axel. Thanks – 
Abdul qadeer
 33 secs ago    Edit   Delete